# ¿como obtener solo la primera fila de un dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Estoy  obteniendo los datos de una api en json y posteriormente los transformo a un dataframe, lo tengo de esta manera

```
url = "https://api-sismologia-chile.herokuapp.com/"
df = pd.read_json(url)
dato_1 = (df.iloc[0, 0])
dato_2 = (df.iloc[0, 1])
dato_3 = (df.iloc[0, 2])
dato_4 = (df.iloc[0, 3])
dato_5 = (df.iloc[0, 4])
dato_6 = (df.iloc[0, 5])
dato_7 = (df.iloc[0, 6])


print(dato_1, dato_2, dato_3, dato_4, dato_5, dato_6, dato_7)
```

esto me devuelve los campos de la primera fila, mi pregunta es como puedo hacer para obtenerlos todo de una sola vez?

Comment: con `df.iloc[0,:]`

Comment: O también `df.head(1)`

Comment: o pasándolos a una lista con `df.iloc[0,:].tolist()`

Comment: gracias gente por el aporte